# Github Pages loose setting for custom domain each time I push to the repo

Tags: azure-devops, gatsby, github-pages

As the title says, each time I push to my Github Pages repository it looses the settings for the custom domain. Why is that?

I am having two repositories for my static blog. The first one is hosted on AzureDevops and private. It contains all the source code of my gatbsy site. The second one is the public repo at Github.

This is the deployment script I am using on AzureDevops to push to my github repo

```
git init 
git config --global user.email "my.mail@address.com"
git config --global user.name "My name"
git remote add origin $(GitHubPagesRepo)
git add . 
git commit -am $Env:Release_ReleaseName
git push origin master --force
```

The variable `$(GitHubPagesRepo)` holds `https://<my token>@github.com/myuser/myuser.github.io.git`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason! Due to the force push I always lost the `CNAME` file in the repository which is required for the custom domain to work.

https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-custom-domains-and-github-pages#cname-errors